# Not able to submit oozie job on kerberized cluster

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, oozie

I am trying to submit a oozie job on to a kerberized cluster.
Below is the command:

```
oozie job -run -DjobTracker=jobtracker-host:8032 -DnameNode=hdfs://namenode-host:8020 -DexamplesRoot=oozie.TestOozieCli.1440674219900/examples -config /tmp/oozie.TestOozieCli.1440674219900/examples/apps/java-main/job_config.xml
```

It is throwing below error:

```
Error: IO_ERROR : java.io.IOException: Error while connecting Oozie server. No of retries = 1. Exception = Could not authenticate, Authentication failed, status: 403, message: Forbidden.
```

Any idea on why i am getting into this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Core-site.xml what is the configuration set for **hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts** & **hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups**

Please try setting like

```
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
    <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
```

Where "**star**" confirms to access all user to submit Job in oozie

After changeing core-site.xml, hadoop need to be restarted.

**EDITED:**

As You mention as concern about Security, on that case, you can mention the seletive User Names by which the Oozie going to received the Job request, instead of mention "**star**" you can mention the User Names, like "oozie,hdfs,hbase,user" on the same property these will also work.

Comment: Hi Sarkar, This actually solved problem. Thanks a lot for your help. But having * for these properties seems too open and may introduce some leaks in security. Now i am looking for alternatives to get over it.

Comment: For reference You can check the [link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Superusers.html) these have mention some alternate option of using for Oozie Job hope these will help some.

Answer (score 0):

Oozie command line uses REST API to connect to Oozie server. If the oozie server is setup to use Kerberos, the REST API will be authenticated with HTTP SPNEGO.

In your case, it seems that http authen failed. You should run a kinit first before oozie commands, such as:

```
kinit -kt {location of your keytab file} {principal}
```

Or just kinit and type the password when prompted:

```
kinit
```